# HashMap NullPointerException in java

Tags: java, exception, hashmap

EDIT:
I have created the wrong object. I needed to use "UndirectedGraphtest" instead of "UndirectedGraph". I just tried to figure out what my problem is and couldnt even see that the problem was directly infront of my eyes. I am so sorry... Thank you guys! (I cant delete this post)

public class UndirectedGraphtest {
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> ownmap;

```
    public UndirectedGraphtest() {
        ownmap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addVertex(Integer i) {
        this.ownmap.put(i, new ArrayList<>());
    }
```

my main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            UndirectedGraph mygraphucidata = new UndirectedGraph();
            mygraphucidata.addVertex(4);
            mygraphucidata.addVertex(5);
Error here->       if(mygraphucidata.ownmap.containsKey(4)) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
```

I dont know if this has anything to do with this problem, but IntelliJ says to my if statement: "'HashMap<String, Integer>' may not contain keys of type 'Integer'" , but I didnt even use HashMap<String,Integer>..., I used HashMap<Integer,ArrayList>

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at UndirectedGraphtest.main(UndirectedGraphtest.java:47)

I know what "NullPointerException" means, but I dont understand what causes this problem here.

Comment: Check that you are using the right class.  `UndirectedGraphtest` and `UndirectedGraph` are different class names.  This could explain both the NPE and the Intellij warning.

Comment: When you actually use `UndirectedGraphtest` then it works just fine.

Comment: @StephenC 
I am so sorry...now it works. sometimes you are programming too long and you cant even find the easiest problems....